# Display a specific spinner depending on radio button selection

Tags: android, android-layout, spinner, radio-group

I am working on an Android application where I want a user to select a RadioButton corresponding to one category, and add a spinner within the same layout, where the displayed spinner depends on the radio button that was selected. This means for each RadioButton I have a different spinner. I know how to add view to the layout but I was wondering how I might go about storing each of the individual spinners and requesting them when the corresponding category is selected. Is it possible to store them within a layout activity and select the correct one using findViewById?

Comment: Attach all the spinners in the activity and listeners accordingly, but handle the visibility of the spinners when category is selected.This might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree to Trushit

add all the spinners in the view & on performing the Radio Button event set the visibility of the spinners.

```
yourSpinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

&

```
yourSpinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```